# Count search results in heading

Tags: posts, search, count

On my wordpress search page I would like to show a 'total found results'. This needs to be shown at the top of the page in a heading.

I've tried this code but I gives me only the results of the specific page. What I want is all the results, not just the page.

```
<?php echo $wp_query->post_count; ?>
```

Comment: `echo $wp_query->found_posts`. Please note, if you've used `query_posts` somewhere, then the main query object will be broken

Comment: dont forget `global $wp_query;` before calling. or use `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->post_count;`

Comment: @taztodgmail You only need to global `$wp_query` if the template was loaded in an unconventional method. Otherwise it will always be available (see `load_template()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [check the documentation for `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) you will notice that `post_count`, which you are using, returns the number of posts being displayed. That is what you see, but not what you want. `found_posts` returns the total number of results for the query, which *is* what you want.

> $post_count
>           The number of posts being displayed.
>
> $found_posts
>           The total number of posts found matching the current query parameters

Note that if your query runs with `'no_found_rows' => true` the `found_posts` value will be 0, and there is a [`found_posts` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/found_posts) that can effect the result as well.